# Primefaces not executing methods with jquery validation

Tags: java, jquery, primefaces

I've recently started to use jquery validation to validate my forms, im also using primefaces 6.0. My problem is that when I try to call any method with a p:commandButton for example and a field doesn't match the required value the jquery validation is triggered before the method is called. Is there anyway to make the jquery validation block the submits from only one button on the form? The save button for instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just seen that its not directly related to jquery validation, the html/primefaces validation also blocks my button to execute the method

Comment: Why not use PrimeFaces CSV (client-side validation)